# Decimal to money string with 3 decimals?

Tags: c#, currency

I have a Decimal field that holds a money value and I want to display it as a money value. I'm using this code:

```
MyMoneyField.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

That works great, however I just got a request to see this value to *three* decimal places. Can you do that with the `CultureInfo`? If not, use round and tack on a `$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the formatting string "C3" instead of "C"

```
MyMoneyField.ToString("C3", new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

See the first table entry on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!